# Función para extraer día de la semana a partir de una fecha

Tags: javascript, date

He escrito una función muy simple para extraer el día de la semana a la que corresponde una fecha, con idea de usarlo próximamente para pasar los parámetros extraídos de una fecha en un XML.

No entiendo la razón por la que no ejecuta la función:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var dia="16";
    var mes="November";
    var anio="2016";
    diaSemana(mes,dia,anio);
},

function diaSemana(dia,mes,anio){
    var dias=["dom", "lun", "mar", "mie", "jue", "vie", "sab"];
    var dt = new Date('"'+mes+' '+dia+', '+anio+' 12:00:00"');
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "Dia de la semana : " + dias[dt.getUTCDay()];    
};
```

Se supone que debería incluirlo en el cuerpo de mi html, pero incluso mirando por consola, me doy cuenta que la función no ejecuta, este es el html:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript getUTCDay Method</title>
  <script src="tiempo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré dos detalles:

- el primero, es el orden en que le pasas los parámetros a la función. Deberían ser en el siguiente orden: (día, mes, año) y los estás enviando (mes, día, año).
- Y el segundo, las comillas dobles no hacen falta al momento de crear
  el Date, si las quitas, quedaría así:

```
var dt = new Date(mes+' '+dia+', '+anio+' 12:00:00');
```

En definitiva, el código seria:

```js
function diaSemana(dia,mes,anio){
    var dias=["dom", "lun", "mar", "mie", "jue", "vie", "sab"];
    var dt = new Date(mes+' '+dia+', '+anio+' 12:00:00');
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "Dia de la semana : " + dias[dt.getUTCDay()];    
};

var dia="16";
var mes="November";
var anio="2016";
diaSemana(dia, mes,anio);
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Son innecesarias las comillas y las horas, cambia:

```
var dt = new Date('"'+mes+' '+dia+', '+anio+' 12:00:00"');
```

por

```
var dt = new Date(mes+' '+dia+', '+anio);
```

Entrada

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    var mes = "November";
    var dia = "16";
    var anio = "2016";
    var dias=["dom", "lun", "mar", "mie", "jue", "vie", "sab"];
    var dt = new Date(mes+' '+dia+', '+anio);
    var text = "Dia de la semana : " + dias[dt.getUTCDay()];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Salida:

```
Dia de la semana : mie
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let days = ['Lunes','Martes','Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado', 'Domingo'];
let d = new Date('02/15/1989'); //Miércoles
console.log(days[d.getUTCDay()-1]);
```

El problema es que la respuesta de `getUTCDay()` es el día de la semana. es decir

- Lunes = 1
- Martes = 2
- Miércoles = 3

etc...

y el Array tiene indice 0.