# Como crear Boton que muestre día de la semana, correspondiente a fecha seleccionada en Input Type Date

Tags: javascript

Hola necesito crear un boton que muestre el día de semana y que se corresponda con la fecha seleccionada a partir de un input type date, estoy usando este código pero no doy con la solución. Soy nueva en este mundo y comenzando en Java. No logro ni siquiera un botón que muestre la fecha. No se que estoy haciendo mal.

```
<html>
      <head>
          <script type="text/javascript">


function mostrardiasemana(){ 
var d=new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
d.setDate[d.getDay() + 1];

var dia=new Array(7);
dia[0]="Domingo";
dia[1]="Lunes";
dia[2]="Martes";
dia[3]="Miércoles";
dia[4]="Jueves";
dia[5]="Viernes";
dia[6]="Sábado";
var n= dia[d.getDay()];
document.getElementById("fecha").innerHTML=n;


alert("La fecha seleccionada en el elemento fecha es un:" + n)}

 
   </script>
</head>
      <body>
                <form>
<p> Fecha de la Encuesta </p>
                <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" min="2019-01-01"
                  max="2021-12-31" value="2019-01-01"/> 
 <button class="botonera" value="Mostrar Dia Semana" onclick="mostrardiasemana"> Mostrar <br/> Día Semana </button>

</form>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Hola @lizbeky  encontre un par de problemas y soluciones similares a tu duda, que te pueden dar una muy buen idea: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34219/funci%C3%B3n-para-extraer-d%C3%ADa-de-la-semana-a-partir-de-una-fecha  y este https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167943/obtener-el-dia-de-semana-segun-una-fecha-en-javascript

Comment: No me parece necesario que al `getDay()` le sumes 1, pues asi te estaría llevando al índice del día siguiente que eliges, al menos si lo quitas debería funcionar igual de bien

Answer (score 1):

Estabas casi, te faltaba indicar en el `onClick` que estabas asignándole un método con los paréntesis; además en el código te faltaba sumarle un día al `getDay()`. Trataste de hacerlo con `setDate`, pero como indica la **[documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)**, esta función sirve para setearle el número de día a una fecha particular y tú lo que tratabas de hacer era indicarle el número que ocupa un día en la semana solamente, por lo que siempre estaría entre 1 y 7.

Dicho esto, te serviría algo así

```js
function mostrardiasemana() {
      var d = new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
      //d.setDate[d.getDay() + 1];
      
      var dia = new Array(7);
      dia[0] = "Domingo";
      dia[1] = "Lunes";
      dia[2] = "Martes";
      dia[3] = "Miércoles";
      dia[4] = "Jueves";
      dia[5] = "Viernes";
      dia[6] = "Sábado";
      var n = dia[d.getDay() + 1];
      document.getElementById("fecha").innerHTML = n;

      alert("La fecha seleccionada en el elemento fecha es un:" + n);
    }
```

```html
<form>
      <p>Fecha de la Encuesta</p>
      <input
        type="date"
        id="fecha"
        name="fecha"
        min="2019-01-01"
        max="2021-12-31"
        value="2019-01-01"
      />
      <button
        class="botonera"
        value="Mostrar Dia Semana"
        onclick="mostrardiasemana()"
      >
        Mostrar <br />
        Día Semana
      </button>
    </form>
```

Sumas un día al momento de setear la variable n y listo!

Nos comentas si te sirvió :D